# How to add an inline function in a tail recursive function

Tags: scala

Say I have the following tail recursive function:

```
@tailrec final def f1(i: Int, j: Int): Int = {
    if (i < j) f1(i + 1, j)
    else if (i < j * 2) f1(i + 2, j)
    else i
}
```

Is there a way I can generalise the addition part while maintaining the function as a tail recursive one? I tried modifying it as follows:

```
@tailrec final def f2(i: Int, j: Int): Int = {
    def add(c: Int): Int = f2(i + c, j)
    if (i < j) add(1)
    else if (i < j * 2) add(2)
    else i
}
```

But I get the following error:

> could not optimize @tailrec annotated method f2: it contains a
> recursive call not in tail position           else if (i < j * 2) add(2)

Comment: If you are in **Scala 3** maybe you can use `inline`

Comment: No I should've specified Scala 2 probably

Answer (score 4):

`@tailrec` doesn't work here because you're calling a different function, `add`, not the original (even though we know it just calls the original), so I don't think it's possible in Scala 2.

Since your objective seems to be to eliminate the need to repeat the constants in the function call - which is all you could hope to do with such an inner function that you're hoping to make tail recursive - you could:

1. Make your inner function tail recursive and use the constant values from the outer scope:

```
final def f3(i: Int, j: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def add(i: Int): Int = 
    if (i < j)          add(i + 1)
    else if (i < j * 2) add(i + 2)
    else                i
  add(i)
}
```

2. [*nasty*] Since tail recursive functions compile to while-loops, just write the while-loop manually, mutable variables and all (left as exercise for reader).

Comment: I was really just using the add as a simple example. The question would be what happens when you have a more complicated block of code that needs to be generalised. And I guess the answer is that it can't be done in Scala 2?

Comment: If it's a complicated block of code, is unlikely it could be tail recursive. A tall recursive function always has to call itself or return a value. Your best bet is still probably an inner tail recursive function, where you can redefine the params. In some circumstances you might make a `Params` case class as the input to your inner "loop" function, and have a complicated code block to output that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always trampoline your code both in Scala 2 and Scala 3 to eliminate any method call whatsoever, even those that are not in tail position at all, no matter their privacy/publicity or finality/non-finality:

```scala
import scala.util.control.TailCalls.{TailRec,tailcall,done}
def f2(i: Int, j: Int): Int = {
  def add(c: Int): TailRec[Int] = tailcall(fun(i + c, j))
  def fun(i: Int, j: Int): TailRec[Int] = {
    if (i < j) add(1)
    else if (i < j * 2) add(2)
    else done(i)
  }
  fun(i, j).result
}
```